# does html cache-control meta effect the images and js files in the page

Tags: html

it seems that the cache-control meta header behavior differences between chrome and ie.Is there any material explain the detail about browser caching images and js files in the page.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

Yes it definitely effects the HTML, CSS and js files you have, Save all the changes you made and refresh the page using `ctrl+f5`.